# Magento Enterprise Admin Login Not Working Suddenly

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I am using magento enterpise. My Admin was not working suddenly.

If logged in with wrong username and password, It's showing "Invalid username/password", but when I tried to logged in with correct username and password(It was redirecting to the same login page).

It was worked for the past 1 year and I didn't do any changes in the server and I didnt apply any patches. Could you please help me in fixing the issue. I am using memcached(aws) for storing the sessions and redis for cache.

Answer (score 0):

Check your cookie domain to make sure it's correct.  If you have access to the database, you can run

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data where path like '%cookie%';
```

to get all of your cookie settings.  If you change something in there, be sure to clear your Magento cache and delete your browser cookies (at least for that domain).

If that doesn't solve it, it may be a problem with writing the session to memcached.  Maybe try clearing memcached manually and ensure Magento can write to it.